# IF SELECT with error "Subquery returned more than 1 value"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
IF (
     SELECT 
            Employees.AnnualDayHollidayAllowance - Employees.TotalHolidaysDaysTaken 
            AS HolidaysRemaining
            FROM Employees) <= 0
     BEGIN
     PRINT  'You have not got enough holidays'
     END
Else

INSERT INTO  RequestedHolidays (Reason,StartDate,EndDate,EmployeeID)
VALUES       (@Reason,@StartDates,@EndDates,@EmployeeID);
```

Can anyone help me with this error message I'm receiving because of this ^, I'm not sure myself what it means

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Your select returns more than one row, as the error states. Try running it on its own and see what you get. Is it what you want?

Comment: Check how to use IF EXISTS

Comment: Beyond that, I'd actually allow the request to be added anyways - when you run out of days, it's not that you can't take off more days, it's that you won't get _paid_ for them.  What happens if there's a bookkeeping issue and the employee _should_ have days available, but it hasn't been resolved yet?  I'd actually prefer to sum up the holidays on-the-fly with the request table and a calendar table.  It looks like your current query doesn't consider the employee, so you're getting everybody in the subquery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first SQL you select rows from WHOLE table `Employees` 
I guess you need it only for current Employee?:

```
IF (
     SELECT 
            SUM(Employees.AnnualDayHollidayAllowance 
                - Employees.TotalHolidaysDaysTaken) 
            AS HolidaysRemaining
            FROM Employees
            WHERE ID = @EmployeeID) <= 0
     BEGIN
     PRINT  'You have not got enough holidays'
     END
Else

INSERT INTO  RequestedHolidays (Reason,StartDate,EndDate,EmployeeID)
VALUES       (@Reason,@StartDates,@EndDates,@EmployeeID);
```

Answer (score 3):

The message is pretty clear.  The subquery in the if returns multiple rows.  Perhaps this does what you want:

```
IF (SELECT sum(Employees.AnnualDayHolidayAllowance - Employees.TotalHolidaysDaysTaken )
    FROM Employees) <= 0
```

or:

```
IF (SELECT sum(Employees.AnnualDayHolidayAllowance - Employees.TotalHolidaysDaysTaken )
    FROM Employees
    WHERE employeeid =  @employeeıd
   ) <= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

the query

```
SELECT 
            Employees.AnnualDayHollidayAllowance - Employees.TotalHolidaysDaysTaken 
            AS HolidaysRemaining
            FROM Employees
```

returns several records for example

```
10
11
12
```

it is not a single number so that it can compare it. you should change your query in a way that it just returns 1 record. something like:

```
SELECT Top (1)
            Employees.AnnualDayHollidayAllowance - Employees.TotalHolidaysDaysTaken 
            AS HolidaysRemaining
            FROM Employees
```